# python+selenium: Element not visible shown while selecting calendar control by click

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am using python selenium and while click a calender control,it shows that element is not visible.I have tried with several methods like JavaScript executor,explicit wait condition, making unique xpath but unable to click and open the calender.it is under iframe.does anyone face this or have solution?Thanks in advance.Here is the HTML code snippet

```
<td xpath="1">

<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtDateOfBirth" type="text" maxlength="10" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtDateOfBirth" class="TextBox" autocomplete="off" style="width:70px;" xpathtest="1">

<input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ibDateOfBirth" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ibDateOfBirth" src="../Images/minical.gif" onclick="javascript:showCalendarControl(document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtDateOfBirth'));return false;WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ibDateOfBirth&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" style="">

<span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rfvDateOfBirth" title="Required" style="color:Red;display:none;">*</span><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rvDateOfBirth" title="Invalid data" style="color:Red;display:none;">*</span>
 </td>
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fnN_cRMARhNEB7T9wwl8yscJhLvf98sh/view?usp=sharing

I tried with below code with Expected condition  like

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
DOB=wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ibDateOfBirth')))
DOB.click()

**and I have also tried with javascript excutor in python like**

DOB=driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ibDateOfBirth")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", DOB)
```

even with xpath also but unable to select as it shows like below

```
File "D:/New folder/SeleniumwithAMBS/calenderpage.py", line 56, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='CalendarControl']/table/tbody/tr[9]/th/a[@href='javascript:hideCalendarControl();']").click()
  File "D:\New folder\SeleniumwithAMBS\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "D:\New folder\SeleniumwithAMBS\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "D:\New folder\SeleniumwithAMBS\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "D:\New folder\SeleniumwithAMBS\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible
  (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.83)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb),platform=Windows NT 10.0.18363 x86_64)


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Try formatting your question better. This is unreadable.

Comment: would u check again please

Answer (score 0):

If the element you want to select is under an iframe, you will need to select it:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
```

Please, provide the link to the page you want to select, so we can verify why your code cannot found it

Comment: foremost i did that to switch to frame even but after that i couldn't

Answer (score 0):

1. Switch to ifrmae:
   driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
2. Wait for the element to show up, and use a unique id like below XPath. I could locate the element (in your provided HTML). Please refer following screen-print.

[Xpath showing calendar icon selsected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qELT.png)

3. I can see 'On Click' action in your HTML, Your provided id points to reference id 'show CalenderControl' on click whereas the error points to reference 'hideCalendarControl'. Please confirm if you are following the sequence in actions like the first click to showCalendarControl and later to hideCalenderControl.

a. If the sequence is not followed, then you might need to initiate showCalenderControl by click.

b. If I assume you followed the sequence then my guess would be showCalendarControl would open control and disappear before your step executes

If it doesn't help, kindly share full HTML and code.